# parsley.js prevents submit after failing ajax validation has been corrected

Tags: ajax, parsley.js, custom-validators

i have a form where i need to see if an email address entered into the form is already in a database. this check needs to be performed conditionally based on the value of another field in the form.

here is the form field:

```
<input type="email" value="" class="form-control" name="email_bill" id="email" required data-parsley-type="email" data-parsley-registered="1" data-parsley-trigger="focusout submit">
```

and here's the validator code:

```
Parsley.addValidator('registered', {
   validateString: function(value) {
   if ($('input[name="d_type"]:checked').val() == 'S') {  
     return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",  
      url: "/is_registered.html",  
      data: $('form').serialize()  
     });
    } else {
         var parent = $('#email').closest('div');
         var this_id = $('#email').attr('data-parsley-id');
         $(parent).removeClass('has-error').addClass('parsley-success');
         $(this_id).remove();
         return true;
         }
   },
   messages: {en: "Someone has already registered with the Email address you entered"}
```

});

the server code is trivial and returns a '200 OK' header if the address isn't in the database and a '404 Not Found' if it is. that works.

i followed the example in the parsley.js custom validator example for the simple ajax request.

what happens is: if i enter a 'registered' address, i get the appropriate error message. if i then go and modify that address to one i know is NOT registered and tab or mouse out to the next field, the error message goes away, BUT the submit button doesn't work. to further complicate the situation, if i load and fill out a form with a 'non-registered' address, the submit button doesn't work either. it appears that execution of the custom validator disables submit upon entry.

i've played with this for hours, trying all sorts of event manipulation, but nothing works.

i should point out that if the checked value of d_type (see field definition above) is NOT 'S', then everything works as expected.

i am totally baffled as to why following the documentation results in failure.

Answer (score 0):

as it turns out, this was not a problem with parsley at all.

a colleague created the form and the submit button had an id of "submit' which  could not allow parsley to resolve the submit handler. under those circumstances, apparently parsley blocks the submit.

who knew?

well now, we know.....